# Can I specify the location of the heap to serialize my data?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to store a program state in a file. So I have a mmapped file that I perform operations on and then save it and maybe use it later.

This is fine for simple things but if I want a long lived data structure that requires dynamic memory allocation, I need a memory allocator that I can force to allocate within the pages I have mmapped.

I'm fairly certain I can't do this with the standard c malloc, and I've looked at jemalloc and I don't know if I can see anything there. I don't know if I'm going the wrong way with this, but is there *any* way to specify the location/size of heap before it is used?

Comment: Not in any C standard way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For something like this you don't really want dynamic memory allocation.  What you want instead is an array which uses an index value of the pointed to element instead of an actual pointer.

Suppose you wanted to implement a binary tree.  You can model it as follows:

```
struct tree {
    int free;
    int value;
    int left;
    int right;
};
```

The `left` and `right` fields contain the indexes of the nodes to the left and to the right of the given node, with the value -1 indicating no such node (i.e. it is equivalent to a NULL pointer in this context).

The `free` field can be used as a flag to determine whether a given element of the array is currently in use.  If a node is marked with `free` equal to 1, the `left` field points to the next free node, making it easy to find free nodes.

Node 0 is special in that it is the start of the free list, and the `right` field points to the root node of the tree.

Then the following tree:

```
              7
           /     \
          3      10
         / \     / \
        1   4   8   12
```

Can be modeled as follows:

```
    free  value   left  right
   ---------------------------
0  |  1  |   0   |  8  |  1  |
   ---------------------------
1  |  0  |   7   |  2  |  3  |
   ---------------------------
2  |  0  |   3   |  4  |  5  |
   ---------------------------
3  |  0  |   10  |  6  |  7  |
   ---------------------------
4  |  0  |   1   | -1  |  -1 |
   ---------------------------
5  |  0  |   4   | -1  |  -1 |
   ---------------------------
6  |  0  |   8   | -1  |  -1 |
   ---------------------------
7  |  0  |   12  | -1  |  -1 |
   ---------------------------
8  |  1  |   0   |  9  |  -1 |
   ---------------------------
9  |  1  |   0   | -1  |  -1 |
   ---------------------------
```

Such a tree can either be memmapped, or kept in memory using `malloc` / `realloc` to manage the size.

If your data structure holds any kind of string, you'll want your structure to contain fixed size character arrays instead of pointers so that they serialize correctly.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if the program is killed while it is modifying the tree structure, the data structure will be incomplete when it is next loaded.